# Should announcements/feedback requests for new Stack Overflow API tools be allowed on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, scope, stackapps

Now that there is a [separate site](https://stackapps.com/) for API-related discussion, etc., are announcements of tools developed with the API appropriate topics for Meta?

I'm bringing this up because there are [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54936/soapi-notify-stay-ahead-of-the-pack-with-new-question-notification-v1-release) [instances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54874/stackwidget-android-homescreen-widget-feedback) of this on the front page at the moment, and I'd like to get some consensus on the issue so everyone with mod powers can use those powers consistently.

Comment: By the way, I asked this because I'm honestly not sure, not because I necessarily want to see those announcement questions removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Announcements regarding tools and applications that use the Stack Overflow API should be posted to [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). **Applications are listed under the ['apps' tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps).**

We used to have API-related discussions on meta, but now that we have a site dedicated for that purpose, application announcements should be posted there.

On meta, they should be closed as off-topic with a link to the new forum.

Comment: I can't get a more official answer than this! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I vote **Yes**, this is the place to contact users, not all of us are developing.