# Is anyone interested in iPhone push notifications for the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, api, iphone

I'm now using the Stack Exchange API to power my native [iPhone Stack Overflow app](https://stackapps.com/questions/1096/geeqe-native-stack-overflow-client) and I'm deciding what to add next. I've run into a number of people who want to have push notifications added but I'm not sure if people just think it will be neat or would actually get something out of it. If you have specific areas you would want to get notifications for please let me know. Notifications will be second on the list of features to add if there seems to be enough interest, first on the list is allowing access to other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: As discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54937/should-announcements-feedback-requests-for-new-stack-overflow-api-tools-be-allowe), you should probably be fielding your feedback requests on API developed tools over on Stack Apps, not Meta. That's the place for all things related to the API now.

Comment: @Grace Fair enough. I'm not sure there are many people there that want to use this app though so if I want any actual feedback this is the only place I can get it.

Comment: Unfortunately many of us would like to advertise our apps here but aren't allowed to. That being said, there's nothing wrong with mentioning it now and again in an answer, IMHO.

Comment: It seems, at the time of this writing, still there is not a free iPhone App capable of deliver push notification from StackExchange sites

Answer (score 3):

Push notification on new answers to your question and comments to you in general would be great.
As would ability to browse sites outside SO. ( For instance, I visit SO very rarely, I'm on SU almost every day & meta once/twice a week).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have push notification of any reputation change and on new answers/comments.

Now I'm not using the API, I'm just reading the main page to see how much reputation I have, making a request every 10 seconds.

Comment: A push notification on *every* vote seems a bit extreme.  Also your rep is updated automatically via web sockets now, there's no need to refresh the page anymore.  The same is true for inbox notifications.