# Is it now suddenly acceptable to post applications as questions here on Meta?

Tags: discussion, policy, stackapps

Yesterday I noticed [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65170).

This question is nothing more than blatant advertisement for an application. My understanding was that this sort of thing belonged on StackApps.

Has the policy changed? Can I start posting my apps here? If the policy has not changed, I think the question ought to be closed and deleted. It's not fair to the rest of us that one person is gaining rep. on Meta by posting apps.

Comment: I wasn't aware of such a policy, but I tentatively support it, assuming that it prevents a lot of clutter.

Comment: *"It's not fair to the rest of us that one person is gaining rep. on Meta by posting apps."* - I was with you until this sentence. Does anyone really care? I agree that the rule on spamming meta about your apps should be applied uniformly, but it's more a matter of signal-to-noise than meaningless rep gain.

Comment: And +1 just because I don't care about whether or not you gain rep :)

Comment: @Jon: The reason I mention the rep. is because that user got 18 upvotes.

Comment: @George - so what? That post is on-topic or off-topic regardless of how many upvotes it got and how many points the author received.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should announcements/feedback requests for new Stack Overflow API tools be allowed on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54937/should-announcements-feedback-requests-for-new-stack-overflow-api-tools-be-allowe)

Comment: @Popular [Here's the original announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54937/should-announcements-feedback-requests-for-new-stack-overflow-api-tools-be-allowe/54940#54940) for the policy. As far as I know, the policy hasn't been changed, so I'm going to vote accordingly.

Comment: @JonSeigel I wouldn't really call a question asking if a policy is still in effect a duplicate of the original policy statement.

Comment: @Grace: Perhaps the policy should be included in one of the FAQs.

Comment: You know what? I'm going to quit MSO, and I advise most of the rest of you to do the same. Please direct any issues you may eventually have to @GraceNote directly.

Comment: @JonSeigel That may be a wise idea. I would say it should be posted on Stack Apps moreso than here... but that's just my thought.

Comment: @Grace: Having it on both sites would eliminate any confusion, though I think it's more about Meta SO policy than StackApps policy.

Comment: @Jon: Ya, we need to be clear about this.